# AJAX Accordion BREAKS when I add table into section

Tags: asp.net, ajax, accordion

Novice developer here...

I've recently discovered the AJAX accordion and it is perfect for what I am trying to create. I have created four sections/panes and I can switch between the panes smoothly. However, once I add a table within the first section (named SECTION ONE in my code below) the entire accordion just breaks. It still loads as usual but nothing happens when I click on the other panes. I have looked online and I have seen evidence that including a table within a section is possible so I must be missing something.

Please can someone assist me?

Many thanks.

```
<table>
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" 
FadeTransitions="true" FramesPerSecond="30" TransitionDuration="350" 
AutoSize="None" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader" 
ContentCssClass="accordionContent">

<Panes>
<asp:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane1" runat="server"><Header><a href="" 
onclick="return false"; class="accordionLink">SECTION 1</a></Header>
<Content>
<table class="accordionTable">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table></Content>
</asp:AccordionPane>
<asp:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane2" runat="server"><Header><a href="" 
onclick="return false"; class="accordionLink">SECTION 2</a></Header>
<Content>EFG</Content></asp:AccordionPane>
<asp:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane3" runat="server"><Header><a href="" 
onclick="return false"; class="accordionLink">SECTION 3</a></Header>
<Content>HIJ</Content></asp:AccordionPane>
<asp:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane4" runat="server"><Header><a href="" 
onclick="return false"; class="accordionLink">SECTION 4</a></Header>
<Content>KLM</Content></asp:AccordionPane>
</Panes>
</asp:Accordion>
</table></form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You should fix the places where you have semicolons in html tags to start: onclick="return false"; (move the semicolon inside the quotes).

Comment: Many thanks for your fast response. Unfortunately that amendment did not resolve the error. As before, if I remove the entire table out of section one, everything works but I really need to be able to include a table. If anyone has any other suggestions, I'd appreciate it sincerely.

Comment: Your issue is actually HTML markup related. You have a bunch of invalid markup. If I paste your code in to the editor it shows all of the issues. Try below...

Comment: You're absolutely correct as there was no reason for the outer table tag to be there. I got so focused on one line of code that I failed to step back and look at the bigger picture. Beginner's mistake, duly noted for the future. Many, many thanks for your help Mjw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of malformed HTML in your markup. I replaced the outermost `<table>` that wraps your Accordion with a `<div>` for demonstration purposes. However, if you require a table to wrap it, you should follow the  conventions in using table structures like so:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>YOUR CONTENT</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Try this:

```
<div>
    <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <ajax:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0"
                FadeTransitions="true" FramesPerSecond="30" TransitionDuration="350"
                AutoSize="None" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"
                ContentCssClass="accordionContent">
        <Panes>
            <ajax:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane1" runat="server">
                <Header><a href="#" onclick="return false" class="accordionLink">SECTION 1</a></Header>
                <Content>
                    <table class="accordionTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </Content>
            </ajax:AccordionPane>
            <ajax:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane2" runat="server">
                <Header>
                    <a href="#" onclick="return false" class="accordionLink">SECTION 2</a>
                </Header>
                <Content>EFG</Content>
            </ajax:AccordionPane>
            <ajax:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane3" runat="server">
                <Header>
                    <a href="#" onclick="return false" class="accordionLink">SECTION 3</a>
                </Header>
                <Content>HIJ</Content>
            </ajax:AccordionPane>
            <ajax:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane4" runat="server">
                <Header>
                    <a href="#" onclick="return false" class="accordionLink">SECTION 4</a>
                </Header>
                <Content>KLM</Content>
            </ajax:AccordionPane>
        </Panes>
    </ajax:Accordion>
</div>
```